# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement'), and barchart did not show

Tags: angular, d3.js

I want to do the bar chart visualization in angular, when the child component gets data from the component, it shows this error, and the bar chart did not show.

Here is my project, someone can help? Thanks a lot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNRRH.png)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2uzmtk?file=src/app/components/bar-chart/bar-chart.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

d3 module is missing from your package, you should install it .

```
npm install d3 && npm install @types/d3 --save-dev
```